# How to grep line which contains two commas

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

I have a file of IP and every line have two or three comma separated IP like -

```
ip x 171.48.179.64, 194.88.105.83, 10.121.15.191
ip x 122.176.17.76, 194.88.105.83, 10.121.15.191
ip x 223.179.196.169, 10.121.15.135
ip x 157.41.161.64, 10.121.15.135
ip x 49.14.160.119, 10.121.15.191
ip x 157.41.230.108, 10.121.15.191
ip x 101.208.189.88, 194.88.105.83, 10.121.15.191
ip x 180.215.137.150, 194.88.105.83, 10.121.15.191
ip x 157.41.161.64, 10.121.15.191
ip x 157.41.161.64, 10.121.15.191
```

So I want to grep the lines which contains two comma (three IPs) like -

```
ip x 171.48.179.64, 194.88.105.83, 10.121.15.191
ip x 122.176.17.76, 194.88.105.83, 10.121.15.191
ip x 101.208.189.88, 194.88.105.83, 10.121.15.191
ip x 180.215.137.150, 194.88.105.83, 10.121.15.191
```

I searched a lot but did't get any specific answer, please help me.

Comment: how about line number 7 and 8th they also having 2 commas why they are not in output? Please elaborate more.

Comment: Yeah, I have shown two lines for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NF==3' file
```

`-F,` sets the delimiter to `,`. `NF` is a special variable which contains the number of fields. If the condition `NF==3` is met awk will print the current line.

---

With (e)grep it would be something like this:

```
grep -E '^([^,]+,){2}[^,]+$' file
```

I would personally use awk because it is much more readable.

Comment: Maybe I've overlooked something? I tried it with your test data and that looked good. What exactly is not working?

Comment: I'm getting the lines which have two IPs

Comment: Well I'm not checking for IPs in particular, just for commas. You say you are getting lines with just 1 comma?

Comment: Sorry my bad, there was one more comma in the log.

Comment: ok, then you need to match the IPs more accurately like  RavinderSingh13 showed.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have other lines too which could have anything else from IPs then following may help you which will check number of fields as well as make sure 1st, 2nd and 3rd fields are having IPs nothing else.

```
awk -F, 'NF==3 && \
$1 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ && \
$2 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ && \
$3 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a loop

```
while read -r line
do
    count=${line//[^,]};
    
    if [ ${#count} == 2 ];
    then 
        echo "${line}";
    fi
done < your.file
```